# Elasticsearch: filter on an aggregation

Tags: database, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, nosql

Since I couldn't find anything on Google:

Is it possible to filter on an aggregation in elasticsearch (5.2). Im thinking of someting like: Get all objects where SUM(obect.X) = 0.

Sample Data

I have the following document-structure:

```
[
  {
    "id": 123,
    "value": -12
  },
  {
    "id": 123,
    "value": 6
  },
  {
    "id": 123,
    "value": 6
  },
  {
    "id": 245,
    "value": 7
  },
  {
    "id": 245,
    "value": -2
  }
]
```

I now want to list all the Ids from the database where the sum of the value is qual to 0.

The following query gives the sum of value for each id

```
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "listingId",
        "size": 1000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "SUM": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "photoCount"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: could you show your mapping.